# Why does this daxpy not work in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

I have this code that's suppose to do the daxpy operation of two vectors and output the result, but it gives me 3 4's when I run it (I think it's suppose to give me 3 6's).

I feel as though I'm missing something of key importance about daxpy, but I have no idea what it is.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



extern "C"
{

    double daxpy_(double *A, double *B, int *n, double *a);
//The daxpy fortran function shown above multiplies a first matrix 'A' by a constant 'a'
//and adds the result to a second matrix 'B.' Both matrices are of size 'n.'
}

void daxpy(double *A, double *B, int n, double a);
//The function above is declared in order to utilize c-notation to perform the fortran
//daxpy function which takes a first matrix 'A' and multiplies the matrix by a costant 'a'
//and then adds the result to a second matrix 'B.'

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double A[3], B[3];
    int n=3;
    double a=1.0;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        A[i]=2;
        B[i]=4;
    }
    daxpy(A, B, n, a);
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cout << B[i] << endl;
    }
}

void daxpy(double *A, double *B, int n, double a)
{
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    B[i]=daxpy_(A, B, &n, &a);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the information on daxpy! Finally! I've commented on the code to make it easier to understand. I was calling daxpy completely wrong. This will work though!!!

The answer is 6 6 6!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


extern "C" //This is important to get the function from the -lblas library you will use when compiling
{
    double daxpy_(int *n, double *a, double *A, int *incA, double *B, int *incB);
//The daxpy fortran function shown above multiplies a first matrix 'A' by a constant 'a'
//and adds the result to a second matrix 'B.' Both matrices are of size 'n.'
}

void daxpy(int n, double a, double *A, int incA, double *B, int incB);
//The function above is declared in order to utilize c-notation to perform the fortran
//daxpy function which takes a first matrix 'A' and multiplies the matrix by a costant 'a'
//and then adds the result to a second matrix 'B.'

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double A[3], B[3]; //Just initializing and filling up some matrices here
    int n=3, incA=1, incB=1;
    double a=1.0;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        A[i]=2;
        B[i]=4;
    }
    daxpy(n, a, A, incA, B, incB); //This is the important part! Note the call notation
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cout << B[i] << endl;
    }
}

void daxpy(int n, double a, double *A, int incA, double *B, int incB)
{
    daxpy_(&n, &a, A, &incA, B, &incB); //Once again, note the call notation. Important!
}
```

How to compile: `g++ (program name) -lblas //Note the -lblas is calling the blas stuff`

Answer (score 2):

Don't you meant to do:

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    A[i]=2;
    B[i]=4;
}
```

That and you're accessing an index outside the bounds of the array. The max index is A[2] for an array size of 3.

Comment: oh...right. That works. I still don't get the right answer though.

Comment: I don't understand. My for loop only goes to 2 the way it is. As the condition I set was that i has to be less than 3. Once it hits 3, it won't run. Oh nevermind. I see what you were talking about now. It's fixed

Comment: That's what it should be doing. This way you index `A[0]`, `A[1]` and `A[2]` which are all the elements in a vector of length 3.